# Use three different quotation marks in a bash command in Python scripts

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I want to have three different quotation marks in a python script, because I want to execute a two-line python command, on a different computer. For example:

```
import commands
command = "ssh someothercomputer 'python -c `import psutil; print psutil.cpu_percent()`'"
output = commands.getstatusoutput(command)[1]
```

However, the backticks are not recognized as quotation marks. The error is the following:

```
"Badly placed ()'s.\nArgument expected for the -c option\nusage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...\nTry `python -h' for more information."
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using backticks, you can escape the inner quotation marks, to have them in `command`. Like this:

```
command =  "ssh someothercomputer 'python -c \"import psutil; print psutil.cpu_percent()\"'"
```

Executing this command with `commands` yields the wanted output (the current cpu percentage at the other computer)